# Print javascript variable in brackets

Tags: javascript, variables, token, document, brackets

Surprisingly I found near to nothing on this topic but I think there´s a very simple solution.

**Problem description:**

I have a Javascript variable which is filled with a PHP variable:

`var createdEncode = '<?php echo $createdEncode; ?>';`

The PHP contains a JSON-string but without the starting and ending curly bracket. I checked for delimiter-problems but that string is  fine how I think, see for yourself:

```
var createdEncode = '"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":15,"iTotalDisplayRecords":11,"aaData":[["1","Suche Kurier","","dauerhaft, immer","","","ein geschenk","3","test dauerhaft","0","1","1","",""],["4","Suche Hilfe","1","bis 09.01.2014, sdfkdsjf","","","Du gibst:  9\u20ac","1","Auch gibt es niemanden, der den Schmerz an sich liebt, sucht ...","1","1","0","",""],["5","Suche Kurier","","bis 15.01.2014, jklkl","","","Du gibst:  8\u20ac","1","jllk","1","1","0","",""],["7","Suche Kurier","","bis 20.01.2014, jkljkl","","","Du gibst:  8\u20ac","1","nm,.","0","1","0","",""],["8","Suche Hilfe","1","am 25.01.2014 um 08:45 Uhr","","","Du gibst:  8\u20ac\/h","2","dsdf","0","1","0","",""],["9","Biete Kurier","","bis 08.01.2014, swrslkjk","","","kljkjl","3","Auto Kompaktklasse, H\u00e4lfte des Kofferraums freier Platz","1","1","0","2","4"],["10","Biete Hilfe","1","am 26.01.2014 um 12:45 Uhr","","","Du bekommst:  6\u20ac","1","sdsdfs","0","1","0","",""],["11","Suche Kurier","","bis 23.01.2014, sfui","","","Du gibst:  7\u20ac","1","jlkkjl","0","1","0","",""],["12","Suche Hilfe","1","am 15.01.2014 um 13:00 Uhr","","","Du gibst:  8\u20ac\/h","2","sdfkl","1","1","0","",""],["13","Biete Kurier","","bis 29.01.2014, erert","","","Du bekommst:  4\u20ac\/h","2","Zu Fu\u00df, Dreiviertel des Kofferraums freier Platz","0","1","0","0","5"],["14","Biete Hilfe","1","dauerhaft, dfgdf","","","Du bekommst:  3\u20ac\/h","2","xfsfds\u00f6k","0","1","0","",""]],"oLanguage":{"sUrl":"language\/dataTables.german.txt"}';
```

Later on I got some JS which says:

```
$('#postsCreatedData').dataTable({
    createdEncode,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aoColumnDefs":[
        {"aTargets .... stuff ...
```

My problem is that "createdEncode" does nothing, the console throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`. Meant is the comma after "createdEncode".

**My approaches:**

I tried it with 
`document.write(createdEncode);` It throws `unexpected token .`.
Also tried `+ createdEncode +`. Same thing here, unexpected + ...
I really don´t know what to do. Can you offer me a solution to print the contents of that variable into that datatable?

Thanks a lot.

**Solution:**

Since Javascript needs a proper object rather than a string to work as intended I had to rewrite the complete datatable()-call. Thanks to MueR for getting me on the right track.

Basically I transformed the printed PHP variable into a standard JSON-object and extended it with the other options which I set to a variable as a JSON-object too.

All I did then is:

`var createdParams = $.extend({}, createdEncode, appendix);` which plugs the "appendix"-JSON to the createdEncode, so the call now works with:

`$('#postsCreatedData').dataTable(createdParams);`

Comment: What does the *generated* JavaScript look like? That's the code that's giving you the error. Figure out what you want to produce before you try to fix the code that produces it!

Comment: It is hard to answer this question, because although you have explained, we simply don't know what the output is on the client-side without seeing it for ourselves. Could you view the source of your web page from the client side and then add to your question exactly what is displayed in the JavaScript as the output of the PHP-parsed line of code here: `var createdEncode = '<?php echo createdEncode; ?>';`

Comment: Ok, I updated my question with the complete string :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're putting a string (without key) in that object, which is invalid.
Your resulting javascript is

```
{
    "a string without index, which is illegal",
    "bAutoWidth": false,
        "aoColumnDefs":[]
}
```

To correctly do it, you would need to have PHP also include the brackets, not the surrounding single quotes, so it's an actual object. Then you would have to merge the `createdEncode` with the other object containing `bAutoWidth` etc.

You could try this (assuming you'll let PHP output an actual javascript object)

```
var dataTableParams = $.extend({}, createdEncode, {"bAutoWidth": false, .. other things ..});
```

Comment: I have to disagree on the brackets. I need to have the string without the brackets, otherwise it would break the code. As you can see every entry in that string is separated with comma. I´m basically adding bAutoWidth and  aoColumnDefs with that commata for getting a valid object available for dataTable().

Comment: The problem is, you're not creating a valid object. In a JS object, every entry must be a key-value pair. You're adding a string without key, which is invalid. Javascript doesn't parse the contents of that variable, and even if it would, it would just see a string. You'll have to convert it to an object and merge them, or add a key (at which point the object you're passing will be valid, but the PHP generated part will still be only a string).

What you want to do cannot be done, it's not how JS works.

Comment: I think I understand you and will try your approach since it is cleaner than mine. But confusing is that I formerly had the line "echo $createdEncode;" instead of createdEncode in there and it worked. So basically when printed with PHP, Javascript only could see a string which contradicts your thought that javascript "would just see a string" and stops.

Comment: If you echo it in that place (in your DataTable call), javascript doesn't know better than it being there. If you put it in a variable and put that variable in, javascript will not replace that variable with the contents of that variable, it will just pass a reference.

Comment: That makes sense and now I understood the problem, thanks :) I´m back when I´ve made progress :)

Comment: You are my hero for today. I will update my question with the solution.